# Mostrar varias descripciones de una lista de arrays en angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un array que con tiene nombre, id y descripción. En el html solo muestro los id con un checkbox que dice seleccionar, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando seleccione varios id's y le de continuar, me muestre la información de todos los id que seleccionó (nombre y descripción).

No se si sea necesario cambiar el checkbox, pero no importa si se puede con otro tipo

```
datos = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' , description:"aaaa"},
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma', description:"aaaa" },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado', description:"aaaa" }
  ];
informacion(){
}
```

html

```
<div  *ngFor="let datos of datos">
{{datos.id}}
<input type="checkbox" >
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo que uses una *property* extra en cada elemento de tu `array`. Esta *property* va a determinar si el elemento está seleccionado o no.

Supongamos la interfaz `Item`

```
export interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
}
```

En tu vista, obtenemos la colección de elementos (`Item[]`) y les añadimos la *property* extra, `checked`

```
type Checkified<T> = T & { checked: boolean };

const checkify = <T>(items: T[]): Checkified<T>[] => {
    const checkifyItem = (item: T): Checkified<T> => ({
        ...item,
        checked: false
    })

    return items.map(checkifyItem);
}
```

De este modo, obtendríamos una colección de tipo `Item & { checked: boolean }`.

Ahora, en el HTML, *bindeamos* el *checkbox* con la *property* `checked`

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of data">
  <!-- ... -->
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.checked" >
</div>
```

Para saber qué elementos están seleccionados, sólo hace falta filtrar por la *property* `checked`

```
get selected(): ItemData {
  return this.data.filter(({ checked }) => checked);
}
```

Donde `ItemData` es `Item & { checked: boolean }`.

Por último, cuando querramos obtener la colección original de `Item[]`, podemos eliminar de nuevo esa *property*

```
get original(): Item[] {
  return this.data.map(item => {
    delete item["checked"];
    return item;
  });
}
```

> `Item` es equivalente, por tanto, a `Omit<ItemData, 'checked'>`.

Dejo un [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4dvnu3?file=src/app/app.component.ts) al ejemplo completo.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias! Sí me funcionó